# Memory leak false positive

Tags: objective-c, xcode, memory-leaks, clang-static-analyzer

I have a simple method in my model to create a NSDictionary object containing its properties.
Unfortunately this method is seen by "Analyse" to be leaking memory :

**Potential memory leak of an object allocated on line 76 (marked here with a dot) and stored in 'dic'.**

```
-(NSDictionary*) getDictionary {
    NSDictionary *dic = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];

    [dic setValue:(id)self.internal_code forKey:@"internal_code"];
    [dic setValue:(id)self.identifier forKey:@"id"];
    [dic setValue:(id)self.owner forKey:@"owner"];
    [dic setValue:(id)self.address forKey:@"address"];
    [dic setValue:(id)self.displayed_name forKey:@"displayed_name"];

    return dic;
}
```

I am not using ARC.

PS : To people coming in, the original code I posted was correct — it had an autorelease. I edited it after so the memory leak would reappear and to ask precisely why.

Comment: How can this code work? You are trying to set the value to NSDictionary. You can not do that.

Comment: Just an unrelated tip. You can make your alloc/init/autorelease into just `[NSDictionary dictionary]`. Many of the standard classes have these convenience constructors.

Comment: Also you say line 76 is your nsdictionary instance but I thought that was dic. It says whatever is leaking is stored in dic and you are not storing the dictionary in itself

Comment: Also, click the blue analyzer warning. It will show you exactly what the problem is, line-by-line, retain-by-retain.

Comment: You need to use NSMutableDictionary.

Comment: Just a note to people coming in. The original code posted was correct with an autorelease. The author later edited the autorelease away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When returning an object from a method that doesn't begin with `alloc`, `copy`, `mutableCopy` or `new`, that object must be returned as autoreleased.

More conceptually, it should not be *owned* by your code when you return it. You take ownership of an object when you type `alloc`, `copy`, `mutableCopy` or `new`. You relinquish ownership when you type `release` or `autorelease`.

You can either change your return statement to:

```
return [dic autorelease];
```

Or better is to keep the `alloc`/`init`/`autorelease` all on one line so the code is easier to review, and the alloc and release cannot become separated by accident while copy and pasting code:

```
NSDictionary *dic = [[[NSDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];
```

An even easier way is to use this convenience constructor on `NSDictionary`:

```
NSDictionary *dic = [NSDictionary dictionary];
```

The above lines will fix the memory leak. However, you are also trying to mutate an immutable type (`NSDictionary`). You should be using a mutable dictionary instead:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dic = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
```

Finally, you should ideally be setting values with the `setObject:forKey:` method, although `setValue:forKey:` will also work.

For more information on memory management, read the [Advanced Memory Management Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/memorymgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html).

If you are targetting iOS 4 or later, I would highly recommend using ARC.

Comment: Alright, indeed, the NSDictionary wasn't really smart. It seems really strange to call autorelease on an object some other method will use, but I guess I should just get used to it.

Thanks for all the tips and the correct answer !

Comment: The autorelease keeps the object alive beyond the scope of the method and until the containining autorelease pool is drained. Typically, for code running on the main thread where you haven't created your own pool, this means your object will stay alive for the duration of the current runloop iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Try to autorelease while returning the dic as below

```
return[dic autorelease];
```

Comment: That would be wrong though. The object is created as autoreleased already. Releasing it again is incorrect.

Comment: Sorry, there was a mistake : I wasn't using autorelease. I corrected the code in my Question.

Comment: well that's your problem then. You need to autorelease it. The original code you posted was correct!

Comment: This type of leaks occur when an allocated object role is finished and you are not releasing it.

Comment: alright, I began iPhone dev a month ago, I still don't have the reflex to use these memory management operations. So basically I always use autorelease and let the AutoReleasePool manage it ? Does every object support this ?